# "Undefined reference" during installation

Tags: linux, installation

I'm trying to install some scientific software (specifically the visualization tools xvs and DV), but I keep getting messages of the form

```
undefined reference to `_gfortran_----_----'
```

or in another case

```
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-redhat-linux/4.4.6/../../../libforms.so: undefined reference to `X----'
```

which eventually lead to errors. I'm very computer illiterate so I have very little understanding of what's happening here and how I can fix it. During configuration it seems to have no trouble locating the Fortran compiler and xforms library (which seem to be implicated here). I'm sure I have gcc-gfortran, libgfortran, xforms, and xforms-devel installed. What might be causing this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your software may depend on versions of some external libraries or other software packages which are older or newer than the ones your system has installed.  You should find out which dependencies your software has *exactly*, i.e. which versions of libraries etc., and which versions of these libraries etc. are installed on your system.

Comment: This may very well be the issue since as far as I can tell the software is pretty old and all the libraries, etc. have been installed very recently. But I don't see references to specific versions in the documentation - where should I look? Also, how would I go about getting older versions? I've just been using yum (this is Scientific Linux 6.2) but I don't know how to select older versions.

Comment: Find out which versions of libraries are installed on your system by `rpm -qi <libraryPackage>` and `rpm -ql <libraryPackage>` which shows the installed files.  For the dependencies of your software: this varies with your build tool.  If you are using autotools with `./configure && make`, you should find a script named `configure` in your source folder which checks the dependencies for your software. You may find the necessary information there -- or in its output while running the build.  It'll probably pass the tests, because your systems has _newer_ libraries than defined in the script.